# Python replace middle digits with commas thousand separator

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a string like this:

```
123456789.123456789-123456789
```

Before and after the decimal/hyphen there can be any number of digits, what I need to do is remove everything before the decimal including the decimal and remove the hyphen and everything after the hyphen. Then with the middle group of digits (that I need to keep) I need to place a comma thousands separators.

So here the output would be:

```
123,456,789
```

I can use lookarounds to capture the digits in the middle but then it wont replace the other digits and i'm not sure how to place commas using lookarounds.

```
(?<=\.)\d+(?=-)
```

Then I figured I could use a capturing group like so which will work, but not sure how to insert the comma's

```
\d+\.(\d+)-\d+
```

How could I insert comma's using one of the above regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't try to insert the thousands separators with a regex; just pick out that middle number and use a function to produce the replacement; [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) accepts a function as replacement pattern:

```
re.sub(r'\d+\.(\d+)-\d+', lambda m: format(int(m.group(1)), ','), inputtext)
```

The `,` format for integers when used in the [`format()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) handles formatting a number to one with thousands separators:

```
>>> import re
>>> inputtext = '123456789.123456789-123456789'
>>> re.sub(r'\d+\.(\d+)-\d+', lambda m: format(int(m.group(1)), ','), inputtext)
'123,456,789'
```

This will of course still work in a larger body of text *containing* the number, dot, number, dash, number sequence.

The `format()` function is closely related to the [`str.format()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) but doesn't require a full string template (so no `{}` placeholder or field names required).

Answer (score 4):

You've asked for a full regular expression here, It would probably be easier to split your string..

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '123456789.123456789-123456789'
>>> '{:,}'.format(int(re.split('[.-]', s)[1]))
123,456,789
```

If you prefer using regular expression, use a function call or lambda in the replacement:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '123456789.123456789-123456789'
>>> re.sub(r'\d+\.(\d+)-\d+', lambda m: '{:,}'.format(int(m.group(1))), s)
123,456,789
```

You can take a look at the different [format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) specifications.